# Merge array with 1st array as object key and 2nd array as its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I combined three arrays using .concat

```
keyArr =  ["meat", "veggies", "fish"]
dataArr = meatArr.concat(vegArr,fishArr);

//value
dataArr = [0: "chicken", 1: "pork", 2: "lettuce", 3: "beans", 4: "shark", 5: "nemo"]
```

I will use the keyArr as my "key" in exchange for the "index" of array. I'm merging the data that i get into my key as an object. Also, separating the odd from even. Expected output:

```
[
{meat: "chicken", veggies: "lettuce", fish:"shark", },
{meat:"pork", veggies: "beans", fish: "nemo"}
]
```

Any advice or approach on how I will work on this is highly recommended. Thanks

Comment: Expected output is invalid (dupe keys)

Comment: Your expected output does not make sense. An object property can only have one value.

Comment: how do you decide the expected output ?

Comment: Closest you'll get will be for each "key" to reference an array of values, like `{meat: ["chicken", "pork"], veggies: [...], fish: [...]}`

Comment: I have to edit the output im sorry. I forgot to separate them

Comment: Are there always an equal number of values for each key, and are they always adjacent as you show here?

Comment: Yes they are always equal in number. I have edited my question please see edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's an equal number of items for each individual array,  create an object of the arrays, iterate one array, and use the keys from the object and the index from the iteration to map the array to a new array of objects.

No need for the `.concat()` array.

```js
var meatArr = ["chicken", "pork"],
    vegArr = ["lettuce", "beans"],
    fishArr = ["shark", "nemo"];
    
var arrays = {meat: meatArr, veggies: vegArr, fish: fishArr};
    
var result = meatArr.map((_, i) => 
  Object.keys(arrays)
        .reduce((res, key) => ({...res, [key]: arrays[key][i]}), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

You may need a transpiler, depending on what JS implementations you're targeting.

Comment: you change the sources.

Comment: @NinaScholz: No, the OP is showing the result of the `.concat()` as a new array assignment, which is a little confusing, but still pretty obviously an attempt to show the result. They should have put it as a code comment instead, like: `// dataArr is now: ["chicken", "pork", "lettuce", "beans", "shark", "nemo"]`